# How to hide all drawers :PROPERTIES:, in the beginning of `org-present` mode, in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, customization, previewing

Is there a startup option I could put in Org mode to hide :PROPERTIES:, or something like that into these presentations with `org-present`?

```lisp
#+STARTUP: latexpreview
#+STARTUP: imagepreview
```

**Clarification:**

**lawlist**:The extension `.el` implies that the file contains Lisp code, not an `org-mode` flat text file where one would normally see a `:PROPERTIES:` drawer. Inasmuch as Emacs does not have a `preset.el` library built-in, where is it that you have that file and why is it relevant to your question?
2 hours ago

**BuddhiLW**:
I'm referring to the org-mode minor-mode called `present`, thus `org-present.el` mode, inside org-mode: [org-present](https://github.com/rlister/org-present). I edited to make it clear what I'm talking about.

**BuddhiLW**:
If you need further clarification, ask for it, and I will be glad to give it. In regards to why is it relevant: when I start the presentation, the `:PROPERTIES:` are not folded. And, they occupy a huge part of the presentation buffer, because it's scaled with the mode, etc. It would be great if they started folded. By changing the `startup`, I believe that could be accomplished without touching the `org-present` package.

Comment: The extension `.el` implies that the file contains Lisp code, not an `org-mode` flat text file where one would normally see a `:PROPERTIES:` drawer.  Inasmuch as Emacs does not have a `preset.el` library built-in, where is it that you have that file and why is it relevant to your question?

Comment: I'm refering to the org-mode minor-mode called `present`, thus `org-present.el` mode, inside org-mode.
https://github.com/rlister/org-present (available in emacs). I edited to make it more clear what I'm talking about

Comment: If you need further clarification, ask for it, and I will be glad to give it. In regards to why is it relevant: when I start the presentation, the :PROPERTIES: are not folded. And, they occupy a huge part of the presentation buffer, because it's scaled with the mode, etc. It would be great if they started folded. By changing the `startup`, I believe that could be accomplished without touching the present package

Comment: Do the built-in initial visibility settings do the trick?:  https://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html

Comment: Try `#+STARTUP: showall` - the default visibility was changed recently to `showeverything` so that first-time Org mode users would not be confused when parts of their file were hidden from view.